# How to extract the first two digits from a string?

Tags: regex, database, postgresql

I have the query below that returns me only the numeric values ​​of my string field, I wanted to limit it to two output characters.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT NULLIF(regexp_replace(temperature, '\D','','g'), '')::numeric AS "Temperature"
from tbl_temperature_hosts
where temperature like '%Core 0%' limit 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
6601205698
```

**EXPECTED OUTCOME**

```
66
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT substring(NULLIF(regexp_replace(temperature, '\D','','g'), '')::numeric::text from 1 for 2)::numeric AS "Temperature"
from tbl_temperature_hosts
where temperature like '%Core 0%' limit 1
```

Comment: Use the ```substring``` perhaps only aroung the ```regexp_replace```.. Saves some casting as well

Answer (score 2):

Use a single regular expression with [back references](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ESCAPE-SEQUENCES):

```
NULLIF(regexp_replace(temperature, '^\D*(\d?)\D*(\d?).*$', '\1\2'), '')
```

`^` and `$` are optional here, but typically make it faster.

Or wrap your expression in `left()` - shorter & faster than `substring()`:

```
left(NULLIF(regexp_replace(temperature, '\D','','g'), ''), 2)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=696851eabda4b4c82290e401541427a5)*